# Import contacts from Firebird DB into OpenLDAP server

Tags: ldap, migration, odbc, firebird

I have a Firebird database with some clients (names, phone numbers, company etc.) in it and I'm trying to import those specific database objects into an OpenLDAP server I set up. My goal is to have those contacts synced between Firebird and the OpenLDAP server and to link the LDAP to a VoIP softphone software so anytime I enter new contacts into Firebird they automatically show up in the phone book register.

I set up an ODBC data source on the same server the Firebird database is located. How do I now use that ODBC driver in conjunction with OpenLDAP to get them to import the data automatically after a new entry in the DB or after a set time period?

Probably unnecessary to add since it's obvious but I'm not well versed when it comes to databases. Maybe you know a simpler way to get data from Firebird into an LDAP directory and I'm just way off.

Comment: Perhaps OpenLDAP server documentation has list of sources which it can use to synchronize with. Otherwise the simplest way is to drop one of contact storages and use only what's left.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and thus off-topic. It might be suitable for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), but check their rules and expectations before posting.